# Using reflection to test methods of inner private class

Tags: java, reflection

Is there a way to test the methods of a private inner class using reflection?
In the code below, how can we test func-1 and func-2

```
public class Outer extends AbstractOuter {
private final Properties properties;

public Outer(Properties properties) {
    this.properties = properties;
}

private class Inner extends AbstractInner {

    private int numOfProperties;

    @Override
    void func-1() throws Exception {
        //
    }

    private int func-2(long l)  {
        //
    }
}
}
```

Comment: "Test behavior, not implementation". If this is a private inner class, it is an implementation detail. Think about the behavior of the class (exposed via its public methods) and test those only.

Comment: I need to test this implementation detail - it is a unit test.

Comment: Similar to @JaroslawPawlak's comment, if certain behavior is best tested, consider refactoring out this behavior into a different object with public methods that can be tested.  The existing object with those private methods can then internally use this new object with tested public behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
package SalesUnitsIntoCarton.mySolution;

import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

public class UtilityReflections {
    private static final Object[] EMPTY = {};

    /**
     * This method returns a value, returned by the method of a private inner class, of a given object instance.
     *
     * @param outerClassInstance This parameter needs to be an instance of the outer class that contains the private inner class.
     * @param attributeNameOfInnerClassInOuterClass This is the name of the attribute that is an inner class type, within the outer class.
     * @param innerClassName This is the class name of the inner class.
     * @param methodNameOfInnerClass This is the name of the method inside the inner class that should be called.
     * @return Returns the value returned by the method of the inner class. CAUTION: needs casting since its of type {@link Object}
     * 
     * @throws SecurityException 
     * @throws NoSuchFieldException 
     * @throws ClassNotFoundException 
     * @throws NoSuchMethodException 
     * @throws InvocationTargetException 
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException 
     * @throws IllegalAccessException 
     * @throws Exception
     */
     public static <T extends Object> Object executeInnerClassMethod(T outerClassInstance, String attributeNameOfInnerClassInOuterClass, String innerClassName, String methodNameOfInnerClass) 
         throws NoSuchFieldException, SecurityException, ClassNotFoundException, NoSuchMethodException, IllegalAccessException,
         IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException {

         final Class<?> outerClass = outerClassInstance.getClass();

         final Field field = outerClass.getDeclaredField(attributeNameOfInnerClassInOuterClass);
         field.setAccessible(true);

         Class<?> innerClass = Class.forName(innerClassName);
         innerClass = field.getType();

         //access the method
         final Method method = innerClass.getDeclaredMethod(methodName, new Class<?>[]{});
         method.setAccessible(true);
         return method.invoke(field.get(outerClassInstance), EMPTY);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is somehow possible with reflection and using `setAccessible(true)` but it will be hard especially as you have private non-static inner classes.

The most interesting question is: **why the hell you want to do so?**

Those inner classes and methods should influence the behavior of the tested outer class. So please test that class!

Trying to test private parts of a class is mostly a signal for lazy testing because you may need less setup, you have legacy code without tests and want to test *only my change*. But sorry, that is useless.

- your test is a white box test bound to the implementation and not the api of the class
- any inner refactoring may break the test even if the overall behavior don't change
- and the most important: you don't test if the inner class or private methods are used the right way (or at all).

**The whole effort to do so is useless, instead test the full class!**

Answer (score 0):

I didn't had to handle this but I think its a good question.
I'm not 100% sure about this but maybe this will work.

```
        Outer.class.getDeclaredClasses()[0].getDeclaredMethod("func-1").invoke(null);
```

I have currently no enviroment to test it. but maybe it helps.

Answer (score -3):

You could test this using mock objects using Mockito.

Comment: Can you please provide more details on how to use Mockito to do it,

Comment: I would go to Mockito website. That has done examples too